# How do I make a component listen for changes in a global variable? angular 5 via service

Tags: angular

I'm building an app in Angular 5 and am trying to create a global variable using my service, 'user_logged_in'. It works, like I can access it from other components, but how do I get a component to reread the variable once it's been updated?

So if a user successfully logs in, I change the variable to true. That part works. But, I have another component (which has already rendered) that will only call for data if a user is logged in. How do I get it to be constantly listening for changes and reevaluate the Boolean to finally load the data once true?

My service looks like:

```js
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

 user_logged_in: Boolean;

}
 constructor(public authService: Http, private router: Router) {}

 logInUser(signInData: { username: string, password: string }): Observable<Response> {
    return this.authService.post('api.url', signInData)
    .map(res => {
      var data = res.json()
      if (data.status = 200){
          this.user_logged_in = true
     }
     return res
   }
  )
}
```

The component looks like:

```js
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sitelist',
  templateUrl: './sitelist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sitelist.component.css']
})

export class SitelistComponent implements OnInit {

  data_returned: boolean;
  logged_in: Boolean;


constructor(public data: DataService, private http: HttpClient, private _dataService: DataService, public authService: AuthService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
  this.data_returned = false;

  //only load data if the global variable is true

  if (this.authService.user_logged_in == true) {
    this.authService.getSites()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data_returned = true;
        this.sites = data;
        this.authService.all_sites = data;
      })
   }
 }
}
```

So, If my component has already loaded and sees 'user_logged_in' as false before the user logs in, how do I get it to reevaluate once the user does? I'd prefer not to refresh the page but instead some sort of synchronous type of evaluation.

Thanks!! let me know how I can clarify anything!

Comment: Actually I think I found an answer for this!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261829/angular-2-component-listen-to-change-in-service

Comment: As you commented, this is a typical use case for a Subject (standard one, a Behaviour Subject, Replay Subject or other, depending on the use case). Also, I recommend you looking at state management solutions, as they aim exactly that. Two good examples are NGRX and NGXS (I personally prefer the later one).

Comment: Voting to Close this as Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Component listen to change in service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261829/angular-2-component-listen-to-change-in-service) in that case.